# Set Size of SWF posted to Facebook with Feed Dialog

Tags: facebook, api, feed, fbjs

Is there a way to set the dimensions of a swf posted to Facebook using the feed dialog, either javascript or direct url method?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain that this works anymore as I've tried to add this with the Feed dialog as opposed to the sharer and it seemed to have no effect at all. It may have been replaced by the source parameter in the newer feed dialog API (which I don't think you can define a width/height for. Please correct me if I'm wrong) ..

but,
take a look at media attachments in the stream attachment guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/

you would pass in a JSON encoded object as the `media` URL param.

```
{"media": [{
    "type": "flash", 
    "swfsrc": "http://www.mapsofwar.com/photos/EMPIRE17.swf", 
    "imgsrc": "http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/funny-pictures-hairless-cat-phones-home.jpg", 
    "width": "80", 
    "height": "60",
    "expanded_width": "160", 
    "expanded_height": "120"
}]}
```

Comment: I think this is an old method that doesn't work with the feed dialog.

Comment: Yeah, you can still define this in the OG however.